# How can I use Sass to style the top bar dropdown menu divider?

Tags: css, sass, zurb-foundation

How can I use Sass to style the TopBar dropdown menu divider (shown as a black line in the image below)?

This portion in `_setting.scss` only seems to apply to the vertical menu dividers:

```
// Divider Styles
$topbar-divider-border-bottom: solid 1px scale-color($topbar-bg-color, lightness: 13%);
$topbar-divider-border-top: solid 1px scale-color($topbar-bg-color, lightness: -50%);
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The code below are just sass variables that are being used for the style of the divider.

```
// Divider Styles
$topbar-divider-border-bottom: solid 1px scale-color($topbar-bg-color, lightness: 13%);
$topbar-divider-border-top: solid 1px scale-color($topbar-bg-color, lightness: -50%);
```

You'll need to find where the actual class '.divider' is being defined and update the styles there.

Comment: As far as I can tell, these two variables have no affect on the submenu divider. I expected otherwise. 

Is that what you see on your end, or did I just miss something?